# React using axios await to fecth jsondata and store it in a variable

Tags: axios, react-tsx

**The data I am retrieving is in JSON format. Would like to store it in a JSON format in some class variable as well. As I want to send the json data to another component.**

````
    // Simple GET request using axios
    axios.get(userDataURL)
        .then((response) => {
         // console.log(response.data);
          jsondata =response.data.json;
          console.log("2"+jsondata);
          this.setState({ users: response.data.results })  
            
        } );   
    }```
````

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: axios already parses data to json/object if it's sent as a json from server. You have to store the data in variable and pass that variable. Need more clarity in question.